# Playbook host_vars

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to set variables for specific hosts in Ansible in the playbook itself, using the the global vars?

So the playbook would be configured something like this:

```yaml
---
- hosts:
    - host-1
    - host-2
  vars:
    host-1: # < - set vars for host-1 specifically
      a_var: yes
    host-2: # < - set vars for host-2 specifically
      a_var: no
```

I know I using either group_vars, host_vars, an inventory file, or set_fact during runtime is possible, but this is not what I want.

The [docs describe](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) "playbook host_vars", but I haven't figured out how that is configured.

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to is not really *in the playbook*, per se. But it can be in the directory structure next to the playbook itself.

This is further explained in [Organizing host and group variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variables).

> Although you can store variables in the main inventory file, storing separate host and group variables files may help you organize your variable values more easily. Host and group variable files must use YAML syntax. Valid file extensions include ‘.yml’, ‘.yaml’, ‘.json’, or no file extension. See [YAML Syntax](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html#yaml-syntax) if you are new to YAML.
>
> **Ansible loads host and group variable files by searching paths relative to the inventory file or the playbook file**.

<sup>*Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variables, emphasis, mine*</sup>

---

So, what you can have is this:

```
.
├── host_vars
│   └── localhost.yml
└── play.yml
```

Where *localhost.yml* matches the name of the host we want to target and would contain something like:

```yaml
foo: bar
```

And the file *play.yml*  would be the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: foo
```

Then running it would give the expected:

```
PLAY [all] **********************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "foo": "bar"
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Q: **"*Set variables for specific hosts in Ansible in the playbook itself, using the global vars.*"**

A: Put the host-specific variables into a global dictionary, e.g. *my_hostvars*. (De facto, create your own *hostvars*). For example

```yaml
- hosts: host-1,host-2
  vars:
    my_hostvars:
      host-1: # < - set vars for host-1 specifically
        a_var: yes
      host-2: # < - set vars for host-2 specifically
        a_var: no
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ my_hostvars[inventory_hostname]['a_var'] }}"
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [host-1] => 
  msg: true
ok: [host-2] => 
  msg: false
```

It's up to you where you declare the dictionary and how you reference it in the playbook. See [Variable precedence: Where should I put a variable?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable).

---

Put the variables into your own *facts* to simplify the access. For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_facts: "{{ my_hostvars[inventory_hostname] }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_facts.a_var
```

give

```yaml
ok: [host-1] => 
  my_facts.a_var: true
ok: [host-2] => 
  my_facts.a_var: false
```

---

You can simplify the access further by setting the variables if needed. (For example, to avoid rewriting a code already using the variables).

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        a_var: "{{ my_facts.a_var }}"
        b_var: "{{ my_facts.b_var }}"
        c_var: "{{ my_facts.c_var }}"
```

---

You can use it to set or customize (precedence 19.) the default values if needed. For example,

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        a_var: "{{ my_facts.a_var|default('a') }}"
        b_var: "{{ my_facts.b_var }}"
        c_var: "{{ my_facts.c_var }}"
```